# Generating dictionaries using a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to build a `Player` class that keeps track of NFL player data. To hold weekly stats I thought I would use a dictionary (`weekly_stats`) that would be comprised of dictionaries that represent week 1-17 (i.e `weekly_stats = {'week1': {'pass_attempts = 0',  #more stats etc}, 'week2': {'pass_attempts = 0',}, # etc on to 'week17'}`. There are a lot of stats and I may add some more another time so instead of copying and pasting that 17 times and manually incrementing the dictionary key, I tried to use a for loop:

```
def Player:
  def __init__(self):
    self.weekly_stats ={}


    for i in range(1,17):
       self.weekly_stats['week'+str(i)]: { # dict keys will be 'week1', 'week2', etc
         'pass_attempts' : 0,
         'completions' : 0, 
          #etc,
          }
  }
```

I am trying to use `i` to say `self.weekly_stats['week1']` , `self.weekly_stats['week2']`, etc through each iteration.

When I create a `Player` object this code seems to run as an object is created and no error is thrown. However, when I try to access this `weekly_stats` dict:

```
print(players['tom_brady'].weekly_stats['week2']['pass_attempts'])
```

it returns `KeyError: 'week2'`. It seems like the dictionary keys are not being created? Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the method 'update' to add a key to a dict

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weekly_stats = {}

        for i in range(1, 17):
            self.weekly_stats.update({"week" + str(i): {
                "pass_attempts": 0,
                "completions": 0,
            }})
```

This article has more info on dict manipulation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary/

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is due to the fact that you are trying to access a key `passing_attempts` where the dictionary has a key `pass_attempts` instead.

The following is a suggested solution:

```
NUM_WEEKS = 16

class Player:
  def __init__(self):
    self.weekly_stats = {
        f'week{i+1}': {
            "pass_attempts": 0,
            "completions": 0
        } for i in range(NUM_WEEKS)
    }

players = {'tom_brady': Player()}
print(players['tom_brady'].weekly_stats['week2']['pass_attempts'])
```